# Was Chatur-ashram applicable for all the different castes?

Tags: caste-system, bramhacharya

Were chaturashram (4 stages of life) applicable for all the 4 castes (Brahmin, Vaishya, Kshatriya, Shudra)? Did lower castes really get the chance to observe bramhacharya, i.e. to be educated?

Comment: It refers to the 3 upper castes, the twice born. But it is caste based upon one's spiritual propensities, not upon what deteriorated over time to become based on birth.

Comment: Everyone including shudras and women got some education or knowledge of their family occupation. They had a duty to perform in this samsara, just as brahmanas had a duty e.g. a shoe-maker's son would be taught how to make shoes, and cart-rider's son would be taught how to ride carts. But only the 3 dvija varna men would be taught Vedic chants.. and shudras could not take sanyasa.

Comment: Any link supporting ur comments!@ram

Comment: Is your question limited to only brahmacharya or all the ashramas in life? The title suggests all but the body is limited to Brahmacharya. You can add all the ashramas.

Comment: I was asking for all ashrams but pointed out brahmacharya because I thought sudras may not allowed to perform brahmacharya. Answers for both ashrams with scriptural evidence are welcome.

Comment: Then please edit the question like that. Because there is already a question was asked after your question about sannyasa. A clear question attracts more users and you will get good answers.

Comment: I am requesting you@Sree Charan to edit my question as am not good in English and hence can't express myself properly.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath:  Good question.

Answer (score 2):

The questions are:

- Were chaturashram (4 stages of life) applicable for all the 4 castes (Brahmin, Vaishya, Kshatriya, Shudra)?
- Did lower castes really get the chance to observe bramhacharya, i.e. to be educated?

---

Yes, it is applicable to  the people of all varnas.

The four ashramas are: Brahmacharya (student), Grihastha (householder), Vanaprastha (retired) and Sannyasa (renunciate).

---

The 4 ashram system is an Ideal system.  It has been devised with a view to driving home the ***idea of liberation/moksha*** into the minds of people.  And, it can happen, if one can shift from ashrama to another smoothly.

It does not mean that everyone will adopt this system.

---

The story of [Jada Bharata](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_4/lectures_and_discourses/the_story_of_jada_bharata.htm) is a perfect example of in spite of one's sincere efforts, how cautious one should remain, so that our mind should not get entangled into the world attachments.

The story of [Dharma Vyadha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyadha_Gita) will be an eye opener to many, who thinks that a Sudra/householder cannot attain wisdom as well as tranquility in the midst of discharging householder's duties.

Answer (score 1):

> Was Chatur-ashram applicable for all the different castes?

**No, Shudras are considered life-long grihasthas.**

Shudras only belong in one Ashrama as per *[Gautama Smriti](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0274.htm)*:

> 55. Live with his wife (only)
>
> 'Another commentator explains the Sûtra to mean that he shall live with his wife only, and never enter another order (i.e. never become a student, hermit, or ascetic).'--Haradatta.

Some more verses:

> Yogi-Yājñavalkya (Parāśaramādhava, p. 537).—‘There are four stages
> prescribed by the Veda for the Brāhmaṇa, three for the Kṣatriya, two
> for the Vaiśya **and one for the Śūdra.’**
>
> Vāmanapurāṇa (Do.).—‘Four stages have been spoken of for the Brāhmaṇa;
> three only, i.e., those of the Householder, the Student, the Hermit,
> for the Kṣatriva; only two—Householdership and Hermitship—for the
> Vaiśya; **only one, that of Householdership, is proper for the Śūdra.’**
>
> Smṛtyantara (Aparārka, p. 966; Parāśaramādhava, p. 538).—‘Having paid
> off the three debts, being freed from all notions of I and mine, the
> Brāhmaṇa, the Kṣatriya and the Vaiśya, [and not the Shudra] may go forth from the house.’